# Where to init variables in order to have clean unit tests?

Tags: angular

I have quite a few places in my project, where I have the following scenario:

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
    permissions$ = this.loadPermissions();

    constructor(private permissionService: MyPermissionService) {}

    private loadPermissions(): Observable<Permissions> {
        return this.permissionService.fetchPermissions('<KEY>');
        // sometimes here will be made some detailed stuff in the pipe for a more specific component
    }
}
```

That means my Observable 'permissions$' will be initialized during the construction of my component and will never be reassigned after it. How on earth would it be possible, to change it dynamically for my unit tests? I don't want to create multiple describe() for every single permission configuration.

Most of the time I'm using something like that:

```
unit-test.spec.ts
it('should ....', () => {
    component.permissions$ = of(<MOCKED_PERMISSIONS>)
});
```

But I think thats not the correct way of doing it, because I only override the resulting Observable, but don't test if the calculation of the permissions work properly.

The approach which I'm using currently, is to init the observable in the ngOnInit():

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    permissions$!: Observable<Permissions>;

    constructor(private permissionService: MyPermissionService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.permissions$ = this.loadPermissions();
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to mock the permissions more easily, because I can reinit the component whenever I want.

```
unit-test.spec.ts
it('should ....', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(permissionService, 'fetchPermissions').and.returnValue(of(...));
    component.ngOnInit(); // triggers a reload containing my mocked data
});
```

It looks nicer in the unit tests, but doesn't in the component itself. I think the initialization directly in the constructor is better than the assignment in the ngOnInit(). Furthermore we have to declare the Observable with the NonNullAssertion '!'.

What is the preferred way for doing it? Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: The value of the property comes from calling a method on a dependency, and is an observable. So why not make that a _subject_ when creating the test double of the dependency, then you can send whatever `.next` value you want in a given test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test observables I think taking control of the source is a better option.
Here i mock the source and emit values, which I can use for my assertions.
You can then play around with it to meet your test case. Hope it sets you on the right path.

```ts
const source = new Subject <Permissions> ();
// you have access to control the observable
const mockService: ServiceType = { ...,
  permissions$: source.asObservable()
};

describe('YourComponent', () => {
      let component: YourComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture <YourComponent> ;

      beforeEach(async() => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [YourComponent],
            providers: [{
              provide: ServiceType,
              useValue: mockService
            }]
          })
          .compileComponents();
      });

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should...', () => {
        component.permissions$.subscribe({
          next: (val) => expect(val).toBe('some Permission value'), // by subscribing, u can inspect the emitted values
          complete: () => {}
        });

        source.next('some Permission value'); // emit some values
        // fixture.detectChanges(); if expecting UI changes
        source.complete(); // remember to complete the source
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, It's a bit unclear for me where ServiceType will be used? Furthermore permissions$ is a variable inside my component, not in the service. I have to set the Subject on component.permissions$. But how to do it? Something like spyOn(component, 'permissions$').and.returnValue(source.asObservable()); doesn't work

Comment: @user2622344 just a little semantic deviation, but `ServiceType` will be your `MyPermissionService`. So when initializing `mockService`, you just put `mockService = { loadPermissions: () => soure.asObservable() }`. The idea is that your `permissions$` observable should come from the `source` Subject, which you control.

Comment: Now i'm completely understand your point. Thank you very much, this is a clever solution. It makes the code more readable